# Carry over users details to a new page

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using wordpress and have created a list of users which are all links. Once clicked I need to carry the person email address over to a form where you can send an email to them directly. So it automatically populates to send with their email address. Currently I have looped through the users I want to send to but stuck on where to go from here:

```
<?php
$args1 = array(
 'role' => 'committee',
 'orderby' => 'user_nicename',
 'order' => 'ASC'
);
 $committee = get_users($args1);


foreach ($committee as $user) {
echo ' 

    <a href="../contact-form?email=' . $user->user_email . '"><b style="font-size:18px;">
  <tr>
    <td style="padding: 10px;">' .$user->job_title .' - </td>
    <td style="padding: 10px;">' .$user->display_name .'</td>
  </tr></b></a><br><br>';

 }

?>
```

I then need to send the persons email address who the user clicked on to this send page:

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="">

    <div class="form-group">

    <label for="InputName">Your name</label>
    <input type="name" class="form-control" id="InputName" placeholder="Enter your name">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">

    <label for="InputEmail">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="InputEmail" placeholder="you@example.com">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">

   <label for="InputMsg">Message</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="8" id="InputMsg" placeholder="Please begin typing your message..."></textarea>   

    </div>    

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Send</button>

     </form>
```

So if you click on a persons name it will take the user to a new page with a contact form, the person who they clicked on will then receive an email once the form is submitted. I just need some advice really on where to begin?

Comment: `'<a href="/foo/url_of_the_form?email=' . $user->email . '">mail him</a>'` and then use `$_GET['email']` in `/foo/url_of_the_form`?

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv So I have made the changes and this is my url /contact-form/?email= it takes me to the page but would appear to not be pulling the person email across?

Comment: I'm pretty sure `$user->email` is undefined. `get_users` returns an array of `WP_User` objects, so I think you need `$user->user_email`. My code was supposed to be a guide only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do this...

```
<td style="padding: 10px;">
    <a href="urlwheretogetform?email=<?php echo $user->user_email;?>">
      <?php echo $user->display_name;?>
    </a>
</td>
```

Then on your other page...

```
  if(isset($_GET['email'])){
     $email = $_GET['email'];
  }
  // Do wahtever afterwards
```

In more detail

```
  <?php if(isset($_GET)){
           $email = $_GET['email'];
         } else {$email='';};?>

  <form role="form" method="post" action="">
   //Your other fields

   <div class="form-group">
   <label for="InputEmail">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="InputEmail" placeholder="you@example.com" value="<?php echo $email;?>">
   </div>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Send</button>

 </form>
```

Comment: Change `$user->email` to `$user->user_email` and you're golden.

Comment: Why would I be using the echo function in the url?

Comment: I am now getting this in my URL /contact-form/?email=<?php%20echo%20user->user_email;?>

Comment: I see what it is meant to be doing, so your taking the users email address and placing it into the url, then on the contact form it takes the users email and uses that to send to. But what I am struggling to see (and I believe I am inputting wrong) why it is posting the php into the url and not just the users email?

Comment: You dont put php echo, if you're doing it inside an echo statement already.  Thats kinda self explanatory really.  You are already echoing, so yes, you would just put the users email, with the php echo, I was just showing the html structure, outside of an echo.  How you have it here ../contact-form?email=' . $user->user_email . '" is fine.  Just a matter of grabbing it on the other side with $_GET

Comment: I am just stuck at the other end of it as to where it gets the email where that would go?

Comment: at the top of the script put <?php $email = $_GET['email'];?> then you can use that $email anywhere in the file

Comment: does the variable need to go into the form?

Comment: I put it in the value field in the example....so yes.  Assuming that form is then submitting and emailing to that address

Comment: No, that field is for a user to input their email address. Once input the email need to go to the person who you clicked on initially. So would that need to be in a hidden field or something?

Comment: I have noticed something however, it is replacing the @ with a . ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56332/discussion-between-user3725879-and-kylek).